# Error: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics. checkNotNullParameter, parameter url while trying to run

Tags: react-native

I have been working on a react native application for sometime, I have been using my linux machine as my main workstation and I have started this project on linux ubuntu environment. But after I decided to migrate to my new Mac machine with ARM architecture I'm getting this error.
Any Ideas would be appreciated ;)

[image]

And the screenshot below is what I have installed for android env
[image]